# Why is geo location giving me POSITION_UNAVAILABLE on all of my browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, geolocation

I have been writing a GeoLocation application this evening. It's been working for hours and recently it stopped. I am now getting

```
PositionUnavailable "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 403."
```

both from Firefox and Chrome. I'm on Linux. I tried applications I did not write myself, like the W3C Schools version, and I get the same error, again on both browsers from this laptop. Even after a reboot. I am getting asked if I want to give permission to allow the websites to see my location. I've accepted and also remembered the decision just to test that.

A friend tried my software, and it works when he uses it from his browser. I tried going to these sites on another computer on my network, also a Linux computer, and it worked just fine.

How do I debug this? Why has it happened to both browsers?

Comment: sometimes the google official demo will also not work-_-

Comment: It is working. I've had friends try this and it works for them. It also works from my other computer as mentioned in the question.